# Create Menu with powerShell

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to create a menu using Powershell, and I have an issue with the list number

The script is like this :

```
# Define the title and options for the menu
$Title = “Select an option:”
$Options = @(
[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(“&A”, “Option A”),
[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(“&B”, “Option B”),
[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(“&C”, “Option C”)
)

# Display the menu and get the user’s selection
$Selection = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, “”, $Options, 0)

# Handle the user’s selection
Switch ($Selection) {
0 { Write-Host “You selected Option A” }
1 { Write-Host “You selected Option B” }
2 { Write-Host “You selected Option C” }
}
```

unfortunately, it shows the menu like this

[1] 1 [2] 2 [3] 3 [4] 4 [?] Help (default is “1”):

I would like to have something like this

[1] Option 1  [2]  Option 2 [3]  Option 3 [4]  Option 4 [?] Help (default is “1”):

Any help, please?

I’m trying to create a menu using Powershell in loop.
when user execute Script it should provide him a list of choices, once option selected, the script should ask user if he would like to make another choice or exit script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor arguments for type [`System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription) are:

- The **label text**, which ***implies* the associated choice character**, by way of **`&` preceding desired character**; e.g., `Option &A` makes `A` the associated character:
- The **associated *help text*** (to be displayed when the user submits `?`)

```bash
$title = "Select an option:"
$options = 'A', 'B', 'C' | ForEach-Object {
  [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(
    "Option &$_",
    "Help for option $_"
  )
}

$selection = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, '', $options, 0)

# Handle the user’s selection
switch ($selection) {
  0 { "You selected Option A" }
  1 { "You selected Option B" }
  2 { "You selected Option C" }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Select an option:
[A] Option A  [B] Option B  [C] Option C  [?] Help (default is "A"): ?
A - Help for option A
B - Help for option B
C - Help for option C
[A] Option A  [B] Option B  [C] Option C  [?] Help (default is "A"): b
You selected Option B
```

---

Note:

- Because it is the *label text* that determines the choice character, **the only way to have *numbered* choices is to in effect *repeat* the number in the label text**.

  - E.g., `'Option A (&1)` would render as `[1] Option A (1)`
  - Note that **you're fundamentally limited to *10* numbered choices** (`1` through `9` + `0`, if acceptable), given that you can only designate a *single* character as the choice character.
- However, you can **use a *workaround* to *hide* the numbers in the label text**: Embed a *backspace* character (`` `b ``) following the choice number, which effectively *erases* it from the label-text display, as shown below.

```bash
$title = "Select an option:"
$number = 1
$options = 'A', 'B', 'C' | ForEach-Object {
  [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(
    "Option $_&$number`b",  # NOTE: `b on display erases the number.
    "Help for option $_"
  )
  ++$number
}

$selection = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, '', $options, 0)

# Handle the user’s selection
switch ($selection) {
  0 { "You selected Option A" }
  1 { "You selected Option B" }
  2 { "You selected Option C" }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Select an option:
[1] Option A  [2] Option B  [3] Option C  [?] Help (default is "1"): 2
You selected Option B
```

Comment: Thank and for your help.
I got the output like this :
[E] Option EXXXX  [E] Option EXXXX  [E] Option EXXX  [E] Option EXXXX  [Q] Option Quit  [?] Help (default is "E"):
Except for the Quite option, it's possible to have a number listed instead of [E]?

Comment: @IT-Consultant Simply use a label with a number: `"Option &1"`. If you want to hide the binding key from the displayed label, append a backspace control character: `[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("Option with hidden keybinding&1$([char]8)")`, resulting in `[1] Option with hidden keybinding`

Comment: Thank you all for your help and assistance.

a quick question, I would like that based on user choice, the script should do something, how I can tackle this?

Comment: @IT-Consultant, replace the strings such as `"You selected Option A"` with actual operations appropriate for each choice. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, I tested as you mentioned and it's working.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm trying to have a smart thing because all choices will have first to get information and then make a change. all choices will have to get information like this 

When the user chooses an option, basically he selects a role, first I need to check if that role exists or not.

if the role exists, then I need to check the privilege if all ok then it's ok otherwise it will add missing privileges.

I'm able to do it using the below script but I need to enter each time the options individually.

Comment: it's OK, I found it :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @IT-Consultant. In general, it's best to create a _new question post_ for follow-up questions.